# PHP Get image url from user message (string) doesn't work with preg_match_all

Tags: php, html, string, image, url

can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?
It always tell me that it is image, even if it isn't.

EDIT: I need to get the link of image, if there is an image link.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
$msg = "<div class='msg'>[" . $row["time"] . "] <b>" . $row["name"] . ":</b> " . $row["message"];
echo $msg;

    preg_match_all( "/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))\s+/", $msg, $urls );
if ( $urls ){
    echo "ye, its image";
    }
}
```

Comment: if you do `print_r($urls);` after `preg_match_all()` call, what it says?

Comment: the stuff in $msg and then: Array( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not that hard as I thought.

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
$msg = "<div class='msg'>[" . $row["time"] . "] <b>" . $row["name"] . ":</b> " . $row["message"];
echo $msg;

    preg_match_all( "/(https?:\/\/\S+\.(?:jpg|png|gif))\s+/", $msg, $urls );
if ( $urls ){
    echo '<img src=".$urls.">';
    }
}
```